# Rails: Is there a problem using get 'signup' => 'users#new' instead of get 'signup', to: 'users#new'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there a problem using

get 'signup' => 'users#index'

instead of

get 'signup', to: 'users#index'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

No.

---

Not really, the `get` method is prepared to deal with either of them.

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb, line 711
def get(*args, &block)
  map_method(:get, args, &block)
end
```

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb, line 748
def map_method(method, args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  options[:via] = method
  match(*args, options, &block)
  self
end
```

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb, line 1597
#
# Matches a URL pattern to one or more routes.
# For more information, see match[rdoc-ref:Base#match].
#
#   match 'path' => 'controller#action', via: :patch
#   match 'path', to: 'controller#action', via: :post
#   match 'path', 'otherpath', on: :member, via: :get
def match(path, *rest, &block)
```

At the end of the day `match` is called and if you go to see the implementation it has the code to deal with it correctly.

Also, [The Rails Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rails-style-guide#routing) doesn't have any recommendation about this.

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be a problem with either way. The `=>`, called a `hashrocket`, is shorthand for `, to:`.

Comment: `=>` is not a shorthand for `to:`. The arguments passed in the two ways are different: in `'signup' => 'users#index'` there's a single argument, a `Hash`; in `'signup', to: 'users#index'` there are two arguments, a `String` and a named parameter or a `Hash`.